# Rails - flash[:alerts] not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alert

I want to print a simple message as an alert like after a user write his email click on the subscribe button.

`Your email is saved, you'll be contacted for a beta very soon!`

This is my view:

```
<form action="/welcome/subscribe" date-remote="true">
    <div>
        <div id="bottomm">
            <input id="bottom" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="fit" />
        </div>
        <%= alert %>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the subscribe method in my controller :

```
def subscribe
    @test = Test.new
    @test.email = params['email']
    @test.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Your email is saved, you'll be contacted for a beta very soon!"
end
```

But nothing is showing. I saw some people with the same issue as mine on stack but I tried the solutions but it didn't worked.

I tried to do these but none worked for me.

```
flash.keep
flash[:notice] = "..."
flash.now[:notice] = "..."
flash[:alert] = "..."
flash.now[:alert] = "..."
and redirecting after
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a block either in `application.html.erb` or whatever your root view is to actually display the flash, like so:

```
<% if notice.present? %>
   <p><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
```

If not, that could be the problem.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Just one last question! If i remove flash.keep, I cannot see the alert anymore. Like not even a second. But if I keep it the alert will stay forever, is there a way to make it disapear after like 3 secs or after a click ?

Comment: You could use jQuery to target the flash `<p>` tag if you give it a class like this: `$('flash-class').delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");`, which would cause it to fade after 3 seconds.